# integral inequality proof (Cauchy-Schwarz like)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given $\vert u(x,y) \vert \leq \int_0^1 \vert \partial_x u(s_1, y) \vert\, ds_1$ and   $\vert u(x,y) \vert \leq \int_0^1 \vert \partial_y u(x,s_2) \vert\,ds_2$,

I would like to prove that $$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \vert u(x,y) \vert^2 \, dx\, dy \leq  \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \vert \partial_x u(x, y) \vert\ dx\, dy\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \vert \partial_y u (x, y) \vert \, dx\,dy$$

$ u \in C^1(\bar{\Omega})$, where $\bar\Omega = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $u$ vanishes on the boundary

I can see that you could just integrate the two upper bound integrals but I have no idea how I'm supposed to get rid of the s's. Any kind of tips or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the s's? They are just dummy variables, you can just write $  \int_{0}^{1}\left|\partial_{y} u\left(x, \right)\right| d  $ instead

Comment: @CalvinKhor Is it still a dummy variable when you've already differentiated the function with respect to that variable?

Comment: $\partial_y u$ means the partial derivative of $u$ in the second input, you can put whatever variable you want inside a function (but you'd normally put $y$ whenever it doesnt cause confusion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asked to prove
$$ \|u\|^2_{L^2(\bar\Omega)} \le \|\partial_x u \|_{L^1(\bar\Omega)}  \|\partial_y u \|_{L^1(\bar\Omega)}. $$

By integrating $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|u(x, y)| \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left|\partial_{x} u\left(s_{1}, y\right)\right| d s_{1}$ in $y$ we obtain
$$ \int_0^1 \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|u(x,y)|dy \le \|\partial_x u \|_{L^1(\bar\Omega)}.$$
and similarly integrating $\sup_{y\in[0,1]}|u(x, y)| \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left|\partial_{y} u\left(x, s_{2}\right)\right| d s_{2}$ in $x$,
$$ \int_0^1\sup_{y\in[0,1]} |u(x,y)|dx  \le   \|\partial_y u \|_{L^1(\bar\Omega)}. $$

Therefore 
\begin{align} \|u\|_{L^2(\bar\Omega)}^2 =\int_0^1\int_0^1 |u(x,y)|^2 dxdy 
&\le \int_0^1\int_0^1 \sup_{\clubsuit\in[0,1]}|u(\clubsuit,y)| \sup_{\heartsuit\in[0,1]}|u(x,\heartsuit)| dxdy \\
&=  \int_0^1\sup_{\clubsuit\in[0,1]}|u(\clubsuit,y)|  dy\int_0^1 \sup_{\heartsuit\in[0,1]}|u(x,\heartsuit)| dx \\
& \le  \|\partial_x u \|_{L^1(\bar\Omega)}  \|\partial_y u \|_{L^1(\bar\Omega)}. \end{align}